# Как организовать приложение на PyQt, работающее в трее?

Tags: python, pyqt4

Есть код:

```
import os
import sys
import types

from collections import OrderedDict
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class SetTrayIcon(QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon):

    def __init__(self, icon, parent=None):
        self.icon = QtGui.QIcon(QtGui.QPixmap(icon))
        self.parent = parent

        QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon.__init__(self, self.icon, self.parent)
        self.menu = QtGui.QMenu(self.parent)

    def setMenu(self, menu=None):
        """Устанавливает пункты меню на иконке в трее"""

        if not menu:
            menu = []

        # Создаем коллекцию не отсортированых элементов.
        collection = OrderedDict(menu)
        items = collection.keys()  # [имена пунктов]
        functions = collection.values()  # [функции, соотвествующие пунктам]

        for i, item in enumerate(items):
            function = functions[i]
            if isinstance(function, types.MethodType) \
                or isinstance(function, types.FunctionType):
                self.menu.addAction(QtGui.QAction(item, self,
                                    triggered=function))

        self.quitAction = QtGui.QAction("Exit", self,
                                        triggered=QtGui.qApp.quit)
        self.menu.addAction(self.quitAction)

        self.setContextMenu(self.menu)

def show(icon=None, menu=None):
    if not isinstance(icon, str) or not icon or not os.path.isfile(icon):
        raise TypeError, "Parameter 'icon' should be the path to the image"

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    trayIcon = SetTrayIcon(icon, QtGui.QWidget())

    if menu and isinstance(menu, list):
        trayIcon.setMenu(menu)

    trayIcon.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

def item1():
    print "Call function <item1>"
def item2():
    print "Call function <item2>"

icon = "/home/zavulon/Programming/Projects/Python2.7/FilesInspector/data" \
       "/image/icon.png"
menu = [(u"item1", item1), (u"item2", item2)]
show(icon, menu)
```

И вот тут мне не понятно: где должен быть основной код приложения, при условии, что он работает в цикле (программа отслеживает изменения файловой системы), если после sys.exit(app.exec_()) никаких действий выполнено быть не может - либо интерфейс замораживается и работает основной код в цикле, либо висит иконка в трее и ничего не происходит? Пробовал через thread, вылазит ошибка.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Кому интересно, вот решение моего вопроса:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import time
import sys
import types

from collections import OrderedDict
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class ProgramTray(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, icon):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
        self.menu = QtGui.QMenu()
        self.icon = QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon(QtGui.QIcon(icon))
        self.flag_exit = True

    def run(self):
        """Код работающий в отдельном потоке"""

        while self.flag_exit:
            time.sleep(2)
            print "I'm working ..."

        QtGui.QApplication.quit()

    def stop(self):
        self.flag_exit = False

    def setMenu(self, menu=None):
        """Устанавливает пункты меню по клику на иконку в трее"""

        if not menu:
            menu = []

        # Создаем коллекцию не отсортированых элементов.
        collection = OrderedDict(menu)
        items = collection.keys()  # [имена пунктов]
        functions = collection.values()  # [функции. соотвествующие пунктам]

        for i, item in enumerate(items):
            function = functions[i]

            if isinstance(function, types.MethodType) \
                or isinstance(function, types.FunctionType):
                self.menu.addAction(QtGui.QAction(item, self,
                                    triggered=function))

        self.quitAction = QtGui.QAction("Exit", self,
                                        triggered=self.stop)
        self.menu.addAction(self.quitAction)

        self.icon.setContextMenu(self.menu)

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

program = ProgramTray(
            "/home/zavulon/Programming/Projects/Python2.7/FilesInspector/data/"
            "image/icon.png")
program.setMenu()
program.icon.show()
program.start()

app.exec_()
```

Иконка висит в трее, программный код выполняется в отдельном потоке.