# Как сделать app indicator в ubuntu unity на python

Tags: python, ubuntu-unity

Облазил множество ресурсов но так и не нашел внятной инфы о том как сделать индикатор приложения в панели unity

Comment: похожий вопрос на AskUbuntu: [How to create Unity indicators?](http://askubuntu.com/q/42211/3712)

Answer (score 1):

Руками, как же еще. Не понятен вопрос: что значит "как сделать"? Это обычная программа! Вас интересует как попасть в полосу уведомлений? Конкретней нужно ставить вопрос, если хотите получить внятный ответ!
Вот пример на PyGTK. По-моему, он гораздо проще нижеследующего примера на PyQt...

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
# PyGTKTrayIcon.py
# Устанавливает иконку  с пунктами меню в системный трей.
#
# [SNIPPET_CATEGORIES: PyGTK]
# [SNIPPET_AUTHOR: João Pinto <joao.pinto@getdeb.net>]
# [SNIPPET_LICENSE: GPL]
#
# Модификация: Иванов Юрий aka HeaTTheatR
# Март, 2015
# Луганск
#
# Email: gleb.assert@mail.ru
# gorodage@gmail.com
#

import os
import types

from collections import OrderedDict

try:
    import pygtk
    pygtk.require("2.0")
    import gtk
    import glib
except ImportError, exc:
    raise ImportError(
        "Install the library 'gtk' and 'pyGTK'\n{0}".format(str(exc))
    )


class PyGTKTrayIcon(gtk.StatusIcon):
    """Устанавливает иконку  с пунктами меню в системный трей"""

    def __init__(self, label, icon, menu, user_function, quit):
        """
        type label: str
        param label: подпись трея

        type icon: str
        param icon: путь к иконке

        type menu: list
        param menu:[("Подпись кнопки", пользовательская функция))]

        type user_function: function
        param user_function: пользовательская функция, вызываетсяа после 
                             установки иконки в трей

        type quit: bool
        param quit: если True - будет создан пункт "Quit" с функцией выхода

        """

        super(PyGTKTrayIcon, self).__init__()

        if icon is not None and os.path.exists(icon) and os.path.isfile(icon):
            self.set_from_file(icon)
        else:
            self.set_from_stock(gtk.STOCK_ABOUT)

        if isinstance(user_function, types.MethodType) or \
                isinstance(user_function, types.FunctionType) or \
               isinstance(user_function, types.BuiltinFunctionType):
            glib.timeout_add(0, user_function)

        self.connect('popup-menu', self.__on_right_click)
        self.set_tooltip(label)

        if not menu:
            menu = [("Quit", gtk.main_quit)]
        if quit:
            menu.append(("Quit", gtk.main_quit))
        self.item_menu = menu

    def __on_right_click(self, icon, event_button, event_time):
        self.__make_menu(event_button, event_time)

    def __make_menu(self, event_button, event_time):
        menu = gtk.Menu()

        # Создаем коллекцию не отсортированных элементов
        collection = OrderedDict(self.item_menu)
        items = collection.keys()  # [имена пунктов]
        functions = collection.values()  # [функции, соответствующие пунктам]

        for i, name_item in enumerate(items):
            function = functions[i]
            if isinstance(function, types.MethodType) or \
                    isinstance(function, types.FunctionType) or \
                    isinstance(function, types.BuiltinFunctionType):
                item = gtk.MenuItem(name_item)
                item.show()
                menu.append(item)
                item.connect('activate', function)

        menu.popup(None, None, gtk.status_icon_position_menu, event_button,
                   event_time, self)


def set(label="", icon=None, menu=None, user_function=None, quit=True):
    PyGTKTrayIcon(label, icon, menu, user_function, quit)
    gtk.main()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    def user_function():
        """Вызывается сразу после уствновки иконки в трей"""

        print "call <user_function>"


    def show_about_dialog(widget=None):
        print "call <show_about_dialog>"


    def show_license(widget=None):
        print "call <show_license>"


    label = "This is the name of your program's"
    menu = [("About", show_about_dialog), ("License", show_license)]
    icon = "./icon.png"

    set(label, icon, menu, user_function)
```

Comment: официальная документация по созданию appindicators отсутствовала какое-то время (есть баг на эту тему -- [можно на archive.org старую документацию откопать](https://web.archive.org/web/20131127160159/http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/application-indicators/)). В любом случае: место для мета-комментариев под вопросом, а не в ответе. "Как сделать" это хлеб и масло Q&A сайтов таких как Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

[Как организовать приложениеt работающее-в трее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/396369/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-pyqt-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B5)

Comment: Во-первых, движок SO не поддерживает разметку phpbb, он использует синтаксис Markdown. Более подробно читайте в [справке](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Во-вторых, хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать выдержку ответа здесь, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника. Ответы-ссылки могут стать недействительными в случае изменения страницы, на которую дана ссылка.